# The renderer function in SCNSceneRendererDelegate is only called by input, not automatically

Tags: swiftui, scenekit

I am aware that this question has been discussed many times before. Nevertheless, it is unclear to me how the whole thing has to be implemented in **SwiftUI**.

*Currently:*

After an input (for example moving the camera) the renderer function is called correctly.

*Goal:*

The renderer function should also be called without needing input.

*Setup:*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var gameData : GameViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        SceneView(
            scene: gameData.scene,
            pointOfView: gameData.camera,
            options: [
                .allowsCameraControl
            ],
            delegate: gameData
        )
    }
}


class GameViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject { ... }


extension GameViewModel: SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the [`rendersContinuously`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/2867339-renderscontinuously) property on `SCNView`.

When working with SwiftUI, there's the [`rendersContinuously`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/sceneview/options/3607697-renderscontinuously) option to use with `SceneView .init(scene:pointOfView:options:preferredFramesPerSecond:antialiasingMode:delegate:technique:)`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much.